# ubuntu package search with multiple terms and logical operators

Tags: apt, package-management, vnc

I mean to search **on the web** for ubuntu pacakges with more than one search term, and logical operators among them.

For instance, I want to search for packages for 20.04 that contain `vnc` and `server` in the *Description*.

So I go to https://packages.ubuntu.com, enter the corresponding parameters, which takes me [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=vnc%20server&searchon=all).
But that finds also VNC clients/viewers, e.g.

> **Package directvnc**
>
> - focal (20.04LTS) (misc): *VNC client using the framebuffer as display* [**universe**]
>
>   0.7.7-1build1: amd64 arm64 armhf ppc64el s390x

and even other packages which do not contain either `vnc` or `server` in the description, e.g.

> **Package mail-stack-delivery**
>
> - focal (20.04LTS) (mail): *transitional package* [**universe**]
>
>   1:2.3.7.2-1ubuntu3.3 [**security**]: all
>
> **Package maas-dhcp**
>
> - focal (20.04LTS): Virtual package
>
>   provided by: maas

I don't know then:

1. **Which packages are included in the search results?**
2. **How to filter only those containing `vnc AND server` in the description?** This is just an example of the type of searches I mean to do.

Notes:

1. In the example, I meant to perform a case insensitive search. I don't know where to specify that, but apparently that is what applies anyway.
2. The *Description* is what is shown in italics in each of the three packages above.
3. If one uses at the CLI `apt-cache show mail-stack-delivery`, the `Description` shows one line with the same text as in italics above. Then a more extended description is shown, but with no `vnc` or `server`.
4. I found an apparent CLI solution with `apt-cache search ".*" | grep -i vnc | grep -i server`. I have faced at least one case when this is not satisfactory: if wa not sitting at an Ubuntu machine, and I wanted to put together a set of instructions for another person which has no knowledge of Ubuntu. In this case, I needed to perform the search online.

Answer (score 0):

Reading `man apt-cache` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html) gives interesting quote:

> **apt-cache** performs a variety of operations on APT's package cache.
> ...
> `search regex`...
> search performs a full text search on all available package lists
> ...
> *Separate arguments can be used to specify multiple search patterns that are **and**'ed
> together.*

So you can use the following syntax locally:

- simple `vnc` **and** `server`:

  ```
  apt-cache search vnc server
  ```

  (on my Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS it gives 51 package name)
- narrowing the result is possible by adding quotes

  ```
  apt-cache search "vnc server"
  ```

  (gives 23 results)

---

For `regex` syntax see `man 7 regex` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man7/regex.7.html).

Comment: This seems a possible refinement on my Note 4.
But do you think it can help with the case of not having an Ubuntu system available?

Comment: In such case you can use Ubuntu inside Docker, VM, WSL/WSL2, GCE console, whatever.

Comment: Great. And do you know the answer to the 2 questions, for the web search?

Comment: Maybe friendlier (with descriptions, but less _grepable_) would be `apt search vnc server`